# Illegal string offset Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to build a 'breadcrumb' thing dynamically using an array and this pass it to the view

In my controller

```
//build the breadcrumbs
$breadcrumbs = [
    [
        'link' => 'test link',
        'name' => ''   
        ]
    ];

return view('home',compact('breadcrumbs'));
```

the 'home.blade.php' extends the 'master.blade.php' where the

```
@include('_breadcrumbs')
```

resides. And here's the contents of '_breadcrumbs.blade.php'

```
<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li @if(!isset($breadcrumbs))class="active"@endif>
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
            </li>
            @if(isset($breadcrumbs))
            @foreach($breadcrumbs as $b)
            <li><a href="{{$b['link']}}">{{$b['name']}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

but it gives me this error

> Illegal string offset 'link' (View:
>   C:\laravel-projects\dinhi_ecommerce\resources\views_breadcrumbs.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\laravel-projects\dinhi_ecommerce\resources\views_breadcrumbs.blade.php)\

If I do

```
dd(var_dump($breadcrumbs));
```

it gives me the contents of the array 'breadcrumbs' which means it does work in the controller part.

Any ideas, help please?

UPDATE:

I actually have a line where I modify the index 'name' in the array which I forgot to include in my post. Anyway I change it from

```
$breadcrumbs['name'] = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first()->cat_name;
```

to

```
$breadcrumbs[0]['name'] = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first()->cat_name;
```

and now its working :)

Comment: can you please add line where you are rendering your page view ?

Comment: do `dd($breadcrumbs)` in view file. Then, what is that result?

Comment: no need to add var_dump in `dd`

Comment: @HermanLuna It was array. Not object

Comment: Can you `dd` or `var_dump()` in view file?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw: I did 'dd' or 'dd(var_dump($breadcrumbs))' and it shows the contents of the array like it worked.

Comment: @HermanLuna No, it will come out error like **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: @CodeDemon I just tried same thing in my machine with laravel 5.2 it works fine.

Comment: I found out the problem, I actually have a line where I insert a value to the 'name' index of the array, the code was wrong "$breadcrumbs['name'] = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first()->cat_name;". I fix it by "$breadcrumbs[0]['name'] = categories::where('cat_id',$id)->first()->cat_name;" Thanks for everyones help :)